# Visa related questions for 3 months voluntary paid internship in Germany / I am an Indian national

Tags: visa, germany

I'm an Indian national planning to move to Germany for a voluntary internship, which I already have an offer for. Voluntary because it's not a part of or in between any ongoing education. And most of the information provided online is catered for students looking at mandatory internships. I have sent mails to the German embassy in India, to the Bundesagentur für Arbeit, and also to VFS Global - but have received no answers from them yet. Which is making it quite difficult for me to get clarity on what needs to be done. Here are several questions I have for now. Thanks in advance.

1. Does my employer start the visa application on my behalf or do I do it on my own? Is my employer's involvement only limited to procuring the ZAV consent letter?
2. Do I have to submit my college qualifications for the ZAV consent letter - considering that mine is a voluntary internship and not a part of any studies?
3. If yes - My first degree (2010) which is in engineering, is recognized by Anabin. But I didn't continue with engineering after college. I got my second degree in film design (2014), but that college isn't recognized until 2015. I worked in films till 2019 after which I jumped to design. I did a vocational design course in Stockholm at a school in 2021, but that isn't recognized in Anabin at all. Now I'm confused about whether my engineering degree from 2010 works as a qualification at Anabin while applying for a visa for a design internship?
4. What other documents are required for the ZAV consent letter? What do I need to provide my employer for them to apply for the ZAV? And what documents/forms do they need to provide/fill from their end? Bear in mind that they're a startup without a dedicated relocation team and have absolutely no idea of the process.
5. Is it mandatory for my company to provide me health insurance? Can I get one on my own?
6. The checklist says that the company needs to provide me with a contract and a proof of employment - what's the difference between the two?
7. Do I need to start any other processes alongside - for instance, starting a bank account, registering for taxes, etc? If I need to and can, how do I go about them without a visa?
8. Lastly, I am prescribed to ADHD meds along with some for anxiety. Since they are classified as narcotics, do I need to apply for any permission to carry medicines into Germany (I remember having to apply for one from the Swedish Medical Agency when I traveled to Stockholm)? Or just a certificate and a valid prescription from my doctor will suffice?

Comment: I'm not even sure you would be eligible for a visa/work authorization, if the internship is not in connection with current studies or very recent studies.

Comment: @xngtng may I know on what basis you think that? Any idea how or where I can cross-check this? Thanks.

Comment: It's not an internship for ZAV if it is not study-related.

Comment: Any source for this?

Comment: https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/datei/dok_ba015615.pdf "Studienfachbezogene Praktika **für ausländische Studierende**" You are no longer a student. Other internships for non-students either require a recognized exchange/scholarship program or are considered as employment requiring a proper work authorization.

Comment: Okay, thanks...